# Behavior of scanf when first format string character is not whitespace

Tags: c, scanf, format-string

`scanf` is supposed to consume and discard any character in the format string that is not part of a conversion specifier.  But its behavior seems different when a *non-whitespace*, *non-conversion* character comes first in the format string. Why?

```
int main() {
    int num, num2;
    printf("> ");
    while (scanf("> %d %d", &num, &num2)) {
        printf("You entered the number %d %d.\n", num, num2);
        printf("> ");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you build and run this and enter

```
> 3 4
```

at the prompt, it prints the message and the repeated prompt and then quits immediately.

So that means that `scanf` returns `2` the first time and then returns `0` before the user can enter another set of tokens. If you remove the `>`  from the format string, the loop will run until the user enters something not a numeral, which then causes `scanf` to return `0` - the behavior I would expect.

Also, if I put that same symbol after the first conversion specifier, the loop continues to run as expected. That is, if the format string has, say, `"%d > %d"`, and the user enters

```
3 > 4
```

the loop will run again and accept another round of input.

I have not seen any documentation on this behavior.

Comment: Instead of `scanf`, why not walk through the string with a pointer and just figure this out yourself? Figuring out simple syntax like this is pretty close to trivial.

Comment: You should be checking that `scanf` returns the number of items that you asked to be converted. You won't know if only 1 item was converted, and will fail when it returns `EOF`.

Comment: The 2nd time around, the newline (from `"> 3 4[ENTER]"`) and the `>` do not match, so `scanf()` stops scanning (leaving the newline in the input buffer) and returns `0`.

Comment: On the second loop, you asked it to match `'>'` with the newline reamining in the input, so it failed.

Comment: Use `" > %d %d"` to avoid that issue. Your read-loop test must be `while (scanf("> %d %d", &num, &num2) == 2)` otherwise, it will fail (spectacularly) if a manual EOF is entered. (see @pmg comment below for proper solution) Read it all into a buffer and then call `sscanf()` on the buffer instead of reading with `scanf()` directly.

Comment: Unrelated: do not use `scanf()` for user input. `scanf()` was not designed for user input. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @pmg: This question is not about how to write good code, it is about the behavior of scanf.  I thought that the newline might be the problem, but scanf is supposed to ignore the newline.  It obviously does _not_ compare the newline to expected input of the first characters are a conversion specifier, so this behavior seems inconsistent.  scanf is nto supposed to try to consume a newline.

Comment: I think that is why he began his comment with `"unrealated:"` ... Bottom line is the `'\n'` is generated by you pressing `[Enter]` following input. `'>'` is NOT a conversion specifier and has no ability to read/discard whitespace. Adding a space before allows zero-or-more whitespace to be discarded. Failing to check `== 2` invites undefined behavior. His point is using `fgets()` and a sufficiently sized buffer avoids that pitfall in `scanf()` use completely.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  See my comments to pmg.  This question is not about how to write good code, and there is no need to try to improve the code.  This question is about pinning down the behavior of a Standard Library I/O function.  Your suggestions are very good for people just learning C, but that is not the purpose of this thread.

Comment: Questions are always about writing good code. Accepting any non-zero value is an error, and people are likely to point them out.

Comment: My first comment addresses your question directly. `scanf()` matches the input with the conversion string except when it finds a `%` or whitespace (`>`is neither). BTW: some `%` conversion specifiers **do not** ignore leading whitespace.

Comment: You wrote: _`scanf` is supposed to consume and discard any character in the format string that is not part of a conversion specifier._. That's not very precise, but is more wrong than right.  Note that prompts written to standard output are not part of the input stream.

Answer (score 5):

From some [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on `fscanf`:

> The format string consists of
>
> - non-whitespace multibyte characters except `%`: each such character in the format string **consumes exactly one identical character** from the input stream, or causes the function to fail if the next character on the stream does not compare equal.

While the `fscanf` specifier `%d` consumes any and all<sup>1</sup> *leading whitespace*, it **does not** consume the line feed that *follows it*, and `'>'` does not **exactly match** that newline character (`'\n'`) on subsequent iterations.

From the same documentation:

> - whitespace characters: any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input (determined as if by calling [*isspace*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) in a loop). Note that there is no difference between `"\n"`, `" "`, `"\t\t"`, or other whitespace in the format string.

So a leading whitespace in your format specifier will consume the trailing newline character from the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, num2;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter \"> NUM NUM2\": ");

        if (2 != scanf(" > %d %d", &num, &num2))
            break;

        printf("You entered the number %d %d.\n", num, num2);
    }
}
```

```
Enter "> NUM NUM2": > 1 2
You entered the number 1 2.
Enter "> NUM NUM2": > 3 4
You entered the number 3 4.
```

---

Aside: this will loop forever on the *truthy* return value of `EOF` (a negative `int`, almost universally `-1`):

```
while (scanf("> %d %d", &num, &num2))
```

You should explicitly check the return value of `scanf` is the *expected* number of conversion specifiers (i.e., `2`).

---

<sup>1. As do all format specifiers **except** `%c`, `%[`, and `%n` (assuming no errors occur).</sup>

Comment: Worth explaining that all conversion specifiers **except** `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` (and `"%n"`) discard leading whitespace. May also want to explain why `" > %d %d"` would work.

Comment: Thank you.  The point I was missing was how leading whitespace is discarded before conversion specifiers but not literal characters.  The point about checking the actual return value is good — I wanted to keep my example simple to illustrate the specific question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Should be covered now, cheers.

Comment: Yep, you got it and the nod.

Comment: @AmittaiAviram Correct *is* simple, though! Less incorrectness means there's less to focus on. That said, the fact that it is rather difficult to *be correct* when using `scanf` is the reason why so many people will advise you to avoid the function (usually in favour of line-based processing) - even if its behaviour can be described.

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with all the comments, especially the ones which emphasize the fact that `scanf` is not really a good idea for user input.

The answer to your question is also mostly given, a trailing newline 'character' is added to the input stream by <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> in the first input, it's not parsed by `scanf` and will remain there, in the second loop that newline will be matched with the first character in the specifier, `>` in this case, and it will fail to match, having `scanf` return 0, breaking the loop.

As suggested, adding a leading whitespace to the specifier will force `scanf` to consume said newline and clear the input buffer which will again wait for input, exposing this behavior.